# Configure JPA Hibernate Debug Logging Programatically

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, logging, log4j

When my CLI app is run with a certain system property, I activate debug logs like:

```
boolean verboseLogging = Boolean.getBoolean("verbose");
if (verboseLogging) {
   org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.Debug);
}
```

I am using the legacy `log4j v1.2.17`

Then there's the part of Hibernate EntityManager v4.2.2.Final configured by JPA persistence.xml:

```
<persistence ...>
   <persistence-unit name="dt">
       <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
       <class>...</class>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Similarly, I would like to set Hibernate loggers to debug level as well as activate Hibernate properties show_sql and hbm2ddl when that flag `verboseLogging` is true. So I have this bit:

```
if (verboseLogging) {
   Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate").setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
   Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate.sql").setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
   Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate.type").setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
   Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl").setLevel(Level.DEBUG);

   Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
   properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
   return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("dt", properties);
}
return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("dt");
```

I've been trying so hard to actually activate the Hibernate debug logs but it's not working!

What am I missing? Is it a missing dependency? 
Note that that Hibernate is actually logging the following:

```
INFO  Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
INFO  Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.2.Final}
INFO  Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO  Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
INFO  Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseASE15Dialect
INFO  TransactionFactoryInitiator - HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
INFO  ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO  Version - Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
WARN  TemplateRenderer - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 1 arguments, but 2 arguments encountered
```

Should I be concerned about `hibernate.properties not found`?